# React Native- Hooks issue

Tags: api, react-hooks, rendering

```
  // Fetch Leads
const getLeadnew = useCallback(() => {
  //fetch('https://3ed6-122-165-218-218.in.ngrok.io/api/Proaddall', {
  fetch(`${BASE_URL}/api/leadsappall`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.leads);
      setLeadnew(res.leads);
      //Filter Method input
      //console.log(Leadnew);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
},);
```

#How to fix multiple re-renders
This can be using the flatlist to view and apply the filter method. Each filter method the data can be re-render the multiple times to get the "cannot convert undefined or null to object". And also using same method to get name to match the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you show some example of the code for future question.

If you want to use the **useEffect** hook to call some api and want only render once you could try add the dependency array to and empty array something like this:

```bash
React.useEffect(() => {
   myApiFunction().then(_ => console.log('myApiFunction'));
  }, []);
```

**myApiFunction** will be the function that have your code to fetch the api with some try catch to handle errors.

I hope this help. cheers